# how to find and replace [0-9]* inside a file, linux

Tags: linux

how can you find [0-9] as this is treated as a pattern by linux

Need to search for 10.179.[0-9]*.150 and replace it with 10.179.227.150 inside a file

Comment: Use escapes: `\[0-9\]\*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `[0-9]*` is a regex pattern:

```
sed -i s/10\.179\.[0-9]*\.150/10.179.227.150/g file.txt
```

If `[0-9]*` is to be taken literally:

```
sed -i s/10\.179\.\[0-9\]\*\.150/10.179.227.150/g file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/10\.179\.[0-9]*\.150/10.179.227.150/g' input.txt >output.txt
```

Or if you meant that the `[0-9]*` must be treated as the literal string, rather than any number of digits, then escape it as `\[0-9\]\*` in the above.